# flutter: ListView inside Expanded widget is not scrolling in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, listview

I want to only scrollable my listtile item. but its not working. If I use the SingleChildScrollView wrap Column widget then it's scrolling but only when I click the column item, not listTile item.

here is my output [image: here is my output]
my expected output is https://prnt.sc/URbiBkWLuXRZ
here is my code

```
SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(flex: 2, child: customAdminDashboard()),
        Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Center(
                    child: Text(
                  "Details of Member",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontFamily: "Montserrat-BoldItalic",
                      color: Color(0xffed8073)),
                )),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 20, right: 20, top: 2, bottom: 2),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: const [
                      Text(
                        "Member Name",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18, color: Color(0xff925093)),
                      ),
                      Text("Balance",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18, color: Color(0xff925093))),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("User-data")
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('Something went wrong');
                    }

                    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Text("Loading");
                    }

                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                          DocumentSnapshot _DocumentSnapshot =
                              snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                          return ListTile(
                            leading: Text(_DocumentSnapshot['Name']),
                            trailing: Text(
                                _DocumentSnapshot['Balance'].toString()),
                          );
                        });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ))
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

I want to scrollable my listTile item only

```
ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                          DocumentSnapshot _DocumentSnapshot =
                              snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                          return ListTile(
                            leading: Text(_DocumentSnapshot['Name']),
                            trailing: Text(
                                _DocumentSnapshot['Balance'].toString()),
                          );
                        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 2, child: customAdminDashboard()),
          Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Details of Member",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat-BoldItalic",
                            color: Color(0xffed8073)),
                      )),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 20, right: 20, top: 2, bottom: 2),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: const [
                        Text(
                          "Member Name",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18, color: Color(0xff925093)),
                        ),
                        Text("Balance",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18, color: Color(0xff925093))),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection("User-data")
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('Something went wrong');
                          }

                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return Text("Loading");
                          }

                          return ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                DocumentSnapshot _DocumentSnapshot =
                                snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                                return ListTile(
                                  leading: Text(_DocumentSnapshot['Name']),
                                  trailing: Text(
                                      _DocumentSnapshot['Balance'].toString()),
                                );
                              });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Please try this

Comment: i do not understand how accept answer

Comment: Beside my answer you will see a tick mark. If you click on it, it becomes an accepted answer

Comment: `ListTile(
                                    leading: Text(index.toString() +
                                        "." +
                                        " " +
                                        " " +
                                        _DocumentSnapshot['Name']),
                                    trailing: Text(_DocumentSnapshot['Balance']
                                        .toString()),
                                  ),`   index is starting with 0 but i want to start with 1,2,3..... [](https://prnt.sc/ASY3lsjUZz6N)  How can i do that

Comment: Text((index+1).toString()

Comment: I am new in flutter that's why so many questions.

Comment: **Kaushik Chandru** is it possible to display text amount start from left side. like this image [](https://prnt.sc/E6abiBb4s5F_)

Comment: Add alignment to text. `textAlign: TextAlign.left`

Comment: TextAlign.left is not work in my case. I use it but not any change in my UI.

Comment: Wrap the text with a SizedBox of width maybe 100